# Woocommerce Product Addon Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to WordPress and can't figured out this error(see link below), basically I have added new plugin for woocommerce but I am getting errors. Do you have any idea on this? TIA

[image: Error encounter]

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late answer, but it looks like that there are multiple instances of a jQuery has been used by your plugins/theme, and they are conflicting with each other.

You can try to disable all of your plugins, and turn them on one-by-one, and you'll see, which one is conflicting with others.

If you can't find which one is responsible for the problem, switch to a different theme, and try it again.

If you find the problem, try not to fix it manually, just notify the plugin/theme author - and pull the new version: your updates will be much easier, without a hack or workaround.

Regards,
Csaba